# C# rhash generates hashes different than the rhash.exe and utorrent

Tags: c#, hash, utorrent

I am using C# with [RHash](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rhash/) in order to calculate the btih hashes of of file.
Currently I'm using  3 tools in order to generate the btih hash:

1. `rhash-1.2.9-src\bindings\mono` with `librhash-1.2.9-win` dll
2. `rhash-1.2.9-win32` command line tool
3. uTorrent

The problem is that every tool generates different btih signatures for the same [file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/simsimy.pub/IMG_0400.JPG) (the photo was taken by me, it's royal free):

```
1:  2FF7858CC0A0B216C3676A807D619FA30101E45F
2:  E6F07BB3C3B3B67531C84E3452980698AC1B0DAA  A:\IMG_0400.JPG
3:  D0B96839A14A8C45BB81AD157805AE73425998E5
```

For the C# hash generation I use `Hasher.GetHashForFile(f.Name, HashType.BTIH);` and `rhash --bith`  in the cmd tool.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to calculate the btih?

Comment: are you sure you use the right encoding? show the code by that you read the file and encrypt it

Comment: Encoding? those are binary files... the rhash binding uses simple FileStream (see line 163 and 77 of the sorcecode https://github.com/rhash/RHash/blob/master/bindings/mono/Hasher.cs)

Comment: thought you might have read the file it into a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the first two is that, according to the `RHash` source code, `BTIH` hashes requires additional data to be correctly computed.

The `init_btih_data` function in `calc_sums.c` is documented with:

> Initialize BTIH hash function. Unlike other algorithms BTIH
>   requires more data for correct computation.

In `test_hashes.c`, the `BTIH` examples are actually treated differently depending on whether `USE_BTIH_WITH_TEST_FILENAME` has been defined.

That `init_btih_data` function (which only seems to get called when running the command line application) in turn calls the `rhash_trasmit` function a number of times depending on various parameters. At a minimum, it will call it twice, which probably explains the difference between the first two. It can, however, call it a number of other times, which I think explains the difference we see with uTorrent.

The difficulty is that while the unmanaged DLL exposes the `rhash_trasmit` function, the .NET bindings do not, which means that it is not possible to supply the additional data that is expected.